# How can I create imports that always work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am struggling a bit to set up a working structure in one of my projects. The problem is, that I have main package and a subpackage in a structure like this (I left out all unnecessary files):

```
code.py
mypackage/__init__.py
mypackage/work.py
mypackage/utils.py
```

The utils.py has some utility code that is normally only used in the mypackage package.

I normally have some test code each module file, that calls some methods of the current module and prints some things to quickcheck if everything is working correctly. This code is placed in a `if __name__ == "__main__"` block at the end of the file. So I include the utils.py directly via `import utils`. E.g mypackage/work.py looks like:

```
import utils

def someMethod():
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(someMethod())
```

But now when I use this module in the parent package (e.g. code.py) and I import it like this

```
import mypackage.work
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'utils'
```

After some research I found out, that this can be fixed by adding the `mypackage/` folder to the PYTHONPATH environment variable, but this feels strange for me. Isn't there any other way to fix this? I have heard about relative imports, but this is mentioned in the [python docs about modules](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html)

> Note that relative imports are based on the name of the current module. Since the name of the main module is always "**main**", modules intended for use as the main module of a Python application must always use absolute imports.

Any suggestions how I can have a `if __name__ == "__main__"` section in the submodule and also can use this file from the parent package without messing up the imports?

**EDIT:** If I use a relative import in `work.py` as suggested in a answer to import utils:

```
from . import utils
```

I get the following error:

```
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

Comment: That will cause an "Attempted relative import in non-package" when he tries to run the module.

Comment: @flammi88 Can you describe how u are running it and from what folder?

Comment: @sureshvv: I am running the modules from the directory where the file resides in. E.g work.py from the mypackage directory and code.py from the parent dir.

Comment: @flammi88: See my updated answer. I am able to replicate your situation and run it successfully under both python2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a structure like this:

```
flammi88
├── flammi88
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── code.py
│   └── mypackage
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── utils.py
│       └── work.py
└── setup.py
```

then put at least this in the setup.py:

```
import setuptools
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='flammi88',
    packages=['flammi88'],
)
```

now, from the directory containing setup.py, run

```
pip install -e .
```

This will make the flammi88 package available in development mode.  Now you can say:

```
from flammi88.mypackage import utils
```

everywhere.  This is the normal way to develop packages in Python, and it solves all of your relative import problems.  That being said, Guido frowns upon standalone scripts in sub-packages. With this structure I would move the tests inside `flammi88/tests/...` (and run them with e.g. `py.test`), but some people like to keep the tests next to the code.

**Update:**

an extended setup.py that describes [external requirements](http://www.scotttorborg.com/python-packaging/dependencies.html) and creates [executables](https://chriswarrick.com/blog/2014/09/15/python-apps-the-right-way-entry_points-and-scripts/) of the sub-packages you want to run can look like:

```
import setuptools
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='flammi88',
    packages=['flammi88'],
    install_requires=[
        'markdown',
    ],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'work = flammi88.mypackage.work:someMethod',
        ]
    }
)
```

now, after pip installing your package, you can just type `work` at the command line.

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure if this is the right way, but I have never heard of the development mode of pip before. I will check the docs about that, but isn't there a more uncomplicated way? I am thinking at the moment about excluding the tests to another file and use relative imports as they sound like the right way to solve the problem...

Comment: `pip install -e ..` does the same as `python setup.py develop`, but it is more convenient if you want to eventually put this into a `requirements.txt` file (just put `-e ...` in the file). It's one directory and two extra files: the `__init__.py` file can be empty, and the `setup.py` file is 6 lines -- it's not that complicated.

Comment: Yes, but this has the issue, that you need to execute a command to make the project runnable. At the moment you can clone the github Repo and everything will just work, when you have all the required third party packages installed... Don't get me wrong, this is at the moment the best answer to my question. I am just curious that python has problems with imports over folder boundaries, which are no problem in C/C++. The python system is superior to this in so many points, I don't see why relative imports are not working when you call a module as main module... However: Thank you!

Comment: "Nobody" will work on your repo like that (cloning and just working on it).  The key phrase is "if they have all the required third party packages installed", meaning, it's not just clone-and-go.. it's clone-run-install-missing-deps-run-install-run-install-... `setup.py` and `requirements.txt` are the methods Python uses to communicate the external dependencies of your project. With those present, then it is just clone-install-and-go. So really you're saving your users a lot of effort. ps: Python doesn't have a problem with relative imports - the problem is with running submodules directly.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately relative imports and direct running of submodules don't mix.

Add the parent directory of `mypackage` to your `PYTHONPATH` or always `cd` into the parent directory when you want to run a submodule.

Then you have two possibilities:

Use absolute (`from mypackage import utils`) instead of relative imports (`from . import utils`) and run them directly as before. The drawback with that solution is that you'll always need to write the fully qualified path, making it more work to rename `mypackage` later, among other things.

**or**

Run `python3 -m mypackage.utils` etc. to run your submodules instead of running `python3 mypackage/utils.py`.

This may take some time to adapt to, but it's the more correct way (a module in a package isn't the same as a standalone script) and you can continue to use relative imports.

There are more "magical" solutions involving `__package__` and `sys.path`  but they all require extra code at the top of every file with relative imports you want to run directly. I wouldn't recommend these.

Answer (score -2):

Import `utils` inside the `work.py` as follows:

```
import mypackage.utils
```

or if you want to use shorter name:

```
from mypackage import utils
```

**EDIT:** If you need to run `work.py` outside of the package, then try:

```
try:
    from mypackage import utils
except ImportError:
    import utils
```

Comment: That causes an `ImportError: No module named mypackage` when trying to run `work.py` directly (from the mypackage directory).

Comment: Sorry, but this obviously a very dark hack :-D This will grow to infinite length everytime I add another layer in the package hierarchy.

Answer (score -2):

Use:

```
from . import utils
```

as suggested by Peter

In your code.py you should use:

```
from mypackage import work
```