# How can we import something from a directory above the main script in the file system hierarchy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, importerror, python-importlib

```
prj
    -pkg_1
        --file1.py
    -pkg_2
        --file2.py
```

Inside `file2.py` we have something like:

```
# Ye be in dis 'ere file which be name-ed `file2.py`

if __name__ == '__main__':

    ## MAGICAL IMPORT STATEMENT HERE ###
    # import Klass from pkg_1/file1.py
    # definitely do not write `from . [blah, blah, blah]`
    # NO DOTS ALLOWED AFTER `from` inside main script!

else: # We not be da main script

    from ..pkg_1.file1 import Klass

    # go to parent directory of current file
    # (parent dir of `file2.py` is `pkg2`)
    # go to parent_directory_of(`pkg2`) == `proj`
    # look for `pkg_1` under `proj`
    # look for `file1` under `pkg_1`
    # look for `Klass` inside `file1`
```

What can we replace `MAGICAL IMPORT STATEMENT` with so that if we run `file2.py` as the main script we do not get `"ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package"`

Comment: You can't do that, intentionally. The right answer is usually to organize your scripts so they're _outside_ the top-level package, not _inside_ it. Often this just means turning those scripts into modules with a `main()` function instead of top-level code, and then writing an "entry-point" script that sits outside the whole thing and does `import pkg1.file1; pkg1.file1.main()`. Or using the tools in `setuptools` to generate those entry-point scripts (and install them onto your path) on the fly.

Comment: If there's some reason that isn't appropriate, you have to either munge `sys.path` (being very careful to avoid the same packages ending up imported both via the `..` path and the `.` path—which is sometimes impossible to be careful about), or explicitly load up the file and pass it to `importlib`, or do various things which are all either much more complicated or much hackier.

Comment: You should just write a `setup.py` file and install your package (example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553589/how-can-i-create-imports-that-always-work/32553711#32553711)